# Azure AD Authentication for Intranet Web Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, claims-based-identity

We are developing Intranet web application using NET framework is 4.6.1 (C#). Both UI (MVC) and backend (Web API) would be deployed as separate web apps in IIS. The requirement is to authenticate user against Azure AD hosted on Cloud. We are able to achieve the same by referring mostly to [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless) article. As soon as user access the Web App, user is redirected to Azure login page and redirected to web app home page after successful authentication.

we are getting multiple roles (admin/user/executive etc.) as claims in MVC but the same roles/claims are not available in Web API. How to get all the claims roles (admin/user/executive etc.) in Web API?

Below is sample code in MVC but the same is not working in Web API.

```
(ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity.Claims
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do will be pass the content of the `Authorization` header (the token) from the request coming into the MVC app as the content for the `Authorization` header for the request going to the Web API app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you please share more details or sample code if possible.